# Blocking messages in one direction on a CAN bus

Tags: can

I have a vehicle that I only want to read CAN bus messages from. But I also have to send out messages on the same bus, but the vehicle may not receive these messages.

Is it possible to block the flow in one direction - so that I can only read from the vehicle, but the vehicle won't receive the messages I send out?

Comment: Two ways to do it: use two different busses or use a CAN isolater.

Comment: This would be why one shouldn't fiddle around on present CAN buses designed by others. Use a separate bus for sending.

Comment: Re: *"the vehicle may not receive these messages"*. Do you mean *"the vehicle must not receive these messages"*?

Comment: What are you sending messages to, if not the vehicle?

Comment: @Mjust .. Are you accurate  about "Want", "can",  "Have to", "Won't"?

Comment: I have a Vehicle and 2 controllers (Controller1 & Controller2)
I have to read from the vehicle to controller 1.
And receive and send between Controller 1 & Controller 2.
But the vehicle must not receive these messages.

Comment: @Mjust Then the solution is obvious: use a separate bus between controller 1 & 2. You can't go crapping down a 3rd party vehicle bus with your own CAN data. If you send anything on that bus, it has to be according to the spec by the person who designed the bus, period.

Answer (score 2):

> But I also have to send out messages on the same bus, but the vehicle may not receive these messages.

This is not possible.

You can be a **silent node**. That cannot transmit or acknowledge.
But you cannot transmit selectively. That is not how CAN bus was designed.

You can also be a hardware silent node by disconnecting `can tx` on the transceiver.

Note that you need at least two functional nodes for communication to be correct. If you add a silent node there must be at least two other nodes in the network.

Comment: Can't i block the flow of messages via a diode! ?

Comment: @Mjust Yes. A diode will block everything. [Introduction: The CAN bus](https://www.kvaser.com/can-protocol-tutorial/)